# Unable to find explicit activity class when trying to start a Service

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have the error when I try to get values of class to other class.
I search on StackOverFlow and try many methods before asking this question.
I think the problem is my class extends from Services.

This is full error in log:

> Unable to find explicit activity class {kr.co.composer.callrecord/kr.co.composer.callrecord.recorder.CallRecordService}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

My code to set values:

```
public class ConfigurationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    btnSaveURL.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String textURL = serverUrl.getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CallRecordService.class);
            i.putExtra("textServerURL", textURL);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

And in class `CallRecordServices.java`:

```
public class CallRecordService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        serverURL = intent.getStringExtra("textServerURL");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

Finally, this is file `Manifest.xml`:

```
<application>
    <service android:name="kr.co.composer.callrecord.recorder.CallRecordService"></service>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `startActivity(i);` but you need to call `startService(i);` instead.

Comment: I was silly. Thank you for pointing that out. 9 minutes I'll accept your question.